# DEBUG_FLAGS in Yocto is always used

Tags: gcc, yocto, bitbake

I tried to build my program via Yocto and faced to problem of large size of executable. After some investigation I found out that my program was built with GCC flag -g (produce debugging info). It's turned out this flag is setted in file bitbake.conf:

```
DEBUG_FLAGS ?= "-g -feliminate-unused-debug-types ${DEBUG_PREFIX_MAP}"

# Disabled until the option works properly -feliminate-dwarf2-dups
FULL_OPTIMIZATION = "-O2 -pipe ${DEBUG_FLAGS}"
DEBUG_OPTIMIZATION = "-O -fno-omit-frame-pointer ${DEBUG_FLAGS} -pipe"
SELECTED_OPTIMIZATION = "${@d.getVar(oe.utils.vartrue('DEBUG_BUILD', 'DEBUG_OPTIMIZATION', 'FULL_OPTIMIZATION', d))}"
```

So flag -g is used in every build, no difference `DEBUG_BUILD` variable is defined or not. The only workaround that I found is to set `${DEBUG_FLAGS} = " "` in my program recipe.

So, my question is: is there any better solutions? And is it normal, that all packages in Yocto are built with debug flag? It seems to be overrun solution, especially for embedded devices.

Comment: Usually yocto builds the binary with debug symbol and extract the debug symbol and store it separately as -dbg package. The actual binary goes into the package won't be with debug symbols. This is needed because, when something breaks or programmer wants to debug the program, then he/she make use of the -dbg package to trace using gdb or anything similar

Comment: In short, you can find the executable with debug symbol (unstripped) in `image` directory and stripped one in `package` directory. Files in `package` directory forms into your package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Parthiban comments. There is no problem in essence.